# Basic C help using arrays and for loops

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, int

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    int Results[8];
    int i = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int maxindex;

    printf("Enter the results of your 7 leavin cert subjects: ");
    do {
        printf("\nSubject %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", Results);
        i++;
    } while (i < 7);

    for (i < 7; Results[i] > 0; i++)
        if (Results[i] > max)
            max = Results[i];
    printf("The best grade is %d", max);
}
```

Hello, so basically I'm trying to print out the largest number(Best result) by using a for loop. However it keeps telling me the that the best result is 0.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `scanf_s("%d", Results)` does?

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", Results);` inputs to the same element - index 0 - in every loop, because the array identifier decays to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Moreover `for (i < 7; Results[i]>0; i++)` gives a compiler warning, since the start condition is probably not what you intend.

Comment: I suggest that you pull out a piece of paper and create a table with rows and columns. At the top of each column, put the name of a variable. For each row, mentally go through each line of code and write down the values of every variable. Now use a debugger to see if your table is correct.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 major problems in your code:

- You read all numbers into `Results[0]` with the `scanf_s("%d", Results);`. You should instead write:

  ```
  if (scanf_s("%d", &Results[i]) != 1) {
      /* not a number, handle the error */
  }
  ```
- The second loop is incorrect: `for (i < 7; Results[i] > 0; i++)` has multiple issues.  Write instead `for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)`

And smaller ones too:

- `#include "stdio.h"` should be written `#include <stdio.h>`
- `#include "stdafx.h"` is not used, and so can be removed - regardless, it should be written as  `#include <stdafx.h>` if it were to be used.
- The `Results` array has size `8`, but you only use `7` slots.
- `main` should have prototype `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent.
- favor idiomatic `for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)` loops over error prone `do / while` loops.
- use braces for a non trivial loop body.

Here is a simpler and better version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int Results[7];
    int i, n, max;

    printf("Enter the results of your 7 leavin cert subjects: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("\nSubject %d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf_s("%d", &Results[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid number\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (n = i, max = 0, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (Results[i] > max)
            max = Results[i];
    }
    printf("The best grade is %d\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the results issue myself alright after looking through it. I really appreciate it.